# How to find & replace URI fragments with Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, text, refactoring, uri

**Hi there!**

I am trying to do a find and replace of URI fragments in a text file but I just don't know how this can be done.

Some resources begin with a URL (E.g. `http://www.example.com/{fragment}`), others begin with a defined prefix (E.g. `example:{fragment}`). Both fragments represent the same object, therefore any alterations to one occurrence must be made to all occurrences of the prefixed and URL fragments and viceversa.

Here's an example:

Every time `http://www.example.com/Example_1` or `example:Example_1` shows up I want to replace all occurrences of the fragment `Example_1` in the file, for a UUID (E.g. `186e4707_afc8_4d0d_8c56_26e595eba8f0`), resulting in all occurrences to be replaced by either `http://www.example.com/186e4707_afc8_4d0d_8c56_26e595eba8f0` or `example:186e4707_afc8_4d0d_8c56_26e595eba8f0`.

This would need to happen for every unique fragment in the file, this means a different UUID for `Example_2`, `Example_3` and so on.

So far I have managed to find that this line of Regex: `(((?<=### http:\/\/archive\.semantyk\.com\/).*)|(?<=archive:)([^\s]+))` works for identifying the fragments, but I really am stuck with the replacing part.

I believe this is not a difficult problem, but I do recognize it's complexity.

I hope I explained myself well enough, but in case I didn't please let me know.

Do you know how this can be solved??

Thank you so much for reading this far along.

---

## EDIT:

I tried using re.sub using this input:

```
###  http://archive.semantyk.com/Abbreviation
archive:Abbreviation rdf:type owl:Class ;
                     rdfs:subClassOf archive:Word .


###  http://archive.semantyk.com/Ability
archive:Ability rdf:type owl:Class ;
                rdfs:subClassOf archive:Quality .
```

and it produces this result:

```
###  http://archive.semantyk.com/4f5b99bb_2bff_4166_8468_0134a1d864ae
archive:4f5b99bb_2bff_4166_8468_0134a1d864ae rdf:type owl:Class ;
                     rdfs:subClassOf archive:4f5b99bb_2bff_4166_8468_0134a1d864ae .


###  http://archive.semantyk.com/4f5b99bb_2bff_4166_8468_0134a1d864ae
archive:4f5b99bb_2bff_4166_8468_0134a1d864ae rdf:type owl:Class ;
                rdfs:subClassOf archive:4f5b99bb_2bff_4166_8468_0134a1d864ae .
```

But this is incorrect since the UUID is the same but the resources (fragments) are not.

Any ideas?

---

## EDIT: SOLVED!

xcan's code solved it! I just made some tweaks for it to work.

Here's the final code:

```
import re
import uuid

def generateUUID():
    identifier = uuid.uuid4().hex
    identifier = identifier[0:8] + '_' + identifier[8:12] + '_' + identifier[12:16] + '_' + identifier[16:20] + '_' + identifier[20:]
    print('Generated UUID: ' + identifier)
    return identifier

def main():
    text = open('{path}', 'r').read()
    # Firsts find what needs to changed.
    rg = r"archive:([^\s]+)"
    matches = re.findall(rg, text, re.M)
    # convert list to a set to get rid of repeating matches
    # then convert back to a list again
    unique_matches = list(set(matches))

    # Change unique words with unique uuids. Same word won't get a
    # different uuid
    for match in unique_matches:
        pattern = r"(?<=archive:)(" + match + ")"
        text = re.sub(pattern, str(generateUUID()), text)

    file = open('{path}', 'w')
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

main()
```

You just need to replace the {path} with the path to your file and that's it! Hope this works for you too.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean using re.sub? https://ideone.com/Gdtbu7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function to re.sub with `repl` argument as seen [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). So you can handle each match with your own set of rules.

### EDIT

Edited according to the comments. `archive:..` matches are found then substituted one by one so same matches located somewhere different in the file gets the same uuid.

```
import uuid
import re


def main():
    text = """  ###  http://archive.semantyk.com/Abbreviation
archive:Abbreviation rdf:type owl:Class ;
                    rdfs:subClassOf archive:Word .
###  http://archive.semantyk.com/Ability
archive:Ability rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf archive:Quality .
                ###  http://archive.semantyk.com/Abbreviation
archive:Abbreviation rdf:type owl:Class ;
                    rdfs:subClassOf archive:Word ."""

    # Firsts find what needs to changed.
    rg = r"archive:([^\s]+)"
    matches = re.findall(rg, text, re.M)
    # convert list to a set to get rid of repeating matches
    # then convert back to a list again
    unique_matches = list(set(matches))

    # Change unique matches with unique uuids. Same matches won't get a
    # different uuid
    for match in unique_matches:
        pattern = r"(?<=archive:)(" + match + ")"
        text = re.sub(pattern, str(uuid.uuid4()), text)

    print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's the thing, it's not. The original file is over 32,000 lines of code containing over 4000 different resources, each with a different fragment. Each resource or fragment has at least two occurrences in the file and most of them are not near each other. There are around 20,000 of these occurrences (many are the same resource but still, different occurrences) I don't think this will quite do it. Any workaround?

Comment: Need to change regex to something like `(((?<=### http:\/\/archive\.semantyk\.com\/).*)|(?<=archive:)(\1))` so end of the URI matches only when there is a `archive:...` counterpart. I'll try...

Comment: There will always be a counterpart since all resources used with the prefix "archive" are declared in the file right after a muted line with the complete URI of the resource as you can see on the first and second line of the code in the edit of the main post, the resource "Abbreviation" appears both in the complete URI form and the prefixed one. This happens with every other resource in the file.

Comment: In fact, it just occurred to me, if we just fix the "archive:" ones, the program I'm using will automatically update the complete URIs.

Comment: So we don't need to change URI parts in the comments? That's an easy fix to code i gave. I can edit the post if you like..

Comment: That's right! No need to change the comments. Please do! :D

Comment: Does it still have to match its counterpart in the comments? Or can we assume if there is an `archive:..` there must be a URI counterpart.

Comment: Not on this code. The comments in this code are only there for documentation and in this particular case the code has been meticulously made so that no URI resources appear in the code, only prefixed resources. There might be a problem though at the top of the document where the declaration of the prefix occurs. Let me know if you would like a photo of the head of the file. As for your question, the same resource may appear many times in the document but all the occurences of the same resource have the same format: "archive:{fragment}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use re (regex) module for replacing a matching pattern, let's look:

```
import re
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```